# Possible ways to manipulate a thread's execution from another thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-3.5, thread-safety

This is a **two part** question.

**First**, let's say that I have a function that is executing in a another thread:

```
private AutoResetEvent StopEvent = new AutoResetEvent( false);

public void WorkerThread()
{
  while( !StopEvent.WaitOne( 10)) {
    a();
    b();
    c();
  }
}
```

Now I want to *pause* this thread.  `Thread.Suspend` is out of the question because it can't guarantee me a deadlock-free system after calling it.  Waiting on another AutoResetEvent is also not desired because of pause "granularity" would be too large.  I have come up with two "solutions", but am not thrilled about either of them (but #2 is preferred at the moment):

1) interleave `PauseEvent.WaitOne()` everywhere:

```
private AutoResetEvent StopEvent = new AutoResetEvent( false);
private ManualResetEvent PauseEvent = new ManualResetEvent( true);

public void WorkerThread()
{
  while( !StopEvent.WaitOne( 10)) {
    PauseEvent.WaitOne( 0);
    a();
    PauseEvent.WaitOne( 0);
    b();
    PauseEvent.WaitOne( 0);
    c();
  }
}
```

2) force a(), b(), and c() to throw a `MyException`.  Then I can wait in the catch block until a "resume" button click signals PauseEvent:

```
private AutoResetEvent StopEvent = new AutoResetEvent( false);
private AutoResetEvent PauseEvent = new AutoResetEvent( false);

public void WorkerThread()
{
  while( !StopEvent.WaitOne( 10)) {
    try {
      a();
      b();
      c();
    } catch( MyException) {
      PauseEvent.WaitOne(); // wait indefinitely until signaled by another thread
    }
  }
}
```

(2) really seems like the only way to do this, but I'd like to know if anyone has tried another method of "pausing".

**Secondly**, the part that I'm getting tripped up on is a nice way for solution #2 to induce the exception in the first place.  At the moment, I've basically instrumented the low-level code called by a(), b(), and c() to look for an event to be signaled that tells them to throw MyException.  This is the only way I know of that you can induce behavior on one thread from another.

What I'd *really* like to know is (and I'm pretty sure it's not possible), is there some crazy way in .NET to make a worker thread register an event handler, so that when I fire the event from my GUI, that the worker thread immediately stops what it's doing and execute the handler?  I guess I'm basically looking for something like an interrupt service routine like what you'd typically implement on a microcontroller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working on a few different approaches to this problem, I think I have something that works well enough.  I basically went with #2, because it leverages the fundamental behavior of an AutoResetEvent for pausing and resuming.

My threads run state machines that are derived from Stateless, so I was able to put all of the pause and resume functionality in the base class, which makes my code nice and clean.  I can also have client-specific functionality by overriding methods in the derived class.

In the end, there were tradeoffs between granularity of pausing and elegance of code.  I sacrificed the granularity so I didn't have to pepper `WaitOne()`s everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a microcontroller-style approach with priority interrupts in .Net. But in the meantime you might want to consider a shared flag that your thread continually checks to see if it should pause or run. Once it detects a request to pause then it can wait using `Thread.Sleep` or a `Timer` to check for permission to run. Perhaps not as elegant as what you were hoping for but it is predictable and easy to implement.

Comment: The flag approach is basically my #1 implementation above.  Sure is a shame that this might be the only way to do it.  I was working on implementation #2 today, but that has its own share of quirky behavior in the system.